# in echo construct why not read comma without double quote

Tags: php

```
<?php

$a="hello bro";
$b="how are u";

echo "$a,$b.<br/>";
echo $a,$b;

?>
```

in php why not read comma(,) in 2nd statement

output-hello bro,how are u
       hello brohow are u

my problem is why not sepate with comma(,). Please give my answer.

Comment: You need to concatenate the string with the variable using `.`

Comment: A comma `,` is an argument separator in PHP: so it isn't displayed in an echo statement unless it's within a quoted string

Comment: It looks like the `echo` command can take multiple parameters, and will concatenate them. So it's not reading the commas as a string, it's parsing it as a parameter separator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the comma with variables use `.` for it

```
echo $a.','.$b;
```

Comment: Comma can be used perfectly with echo, just needs to be outside the quotes. No need to use dot necessarily

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yes can use comma

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $a,$b;
```

will be treated  as

```
echo $a;
echo $b ;
```

SO you may need

```
echo $a,',',$b;
```

or

```
echo $a.','.$b;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first echo statement the comma is part of the string and when the double quote string is parsed the variables are injected into the string. This does not happen with single quotes however as there is no extra parsing for single quoted strings. The benefit of the single quote being that if you are processing a lot of strings, single quotes will run faster as they don't have the extra parsing rules.

So, why does the second statement not work? Well, in the second statement, the comma is parsed as a multiple argument separator. The echo construct allows multiple arguments, each of which will be output (note: the print construct will not take multiple arguments). The comma in this situation is syntax rather than output. If you wanted to achieve the same output using the comma syntax you would need

```
<?php
echo $a,',',$b;
?>
```

or using concatenation

```
<?php
echo $a.','.$b;
?>
```

A general note, in my experience using multiple arguments in an echo statement is faster than using concatenation, especially when concatenating more than two values.